# Are all balls in $L^p$ convex?

Tags: real-analysis

Are all balls in $L^p$ convex? The case when $p \geq 1$ is talked about a lot. What about when $p<1$? If $L^p$ behaves like $\ell^p$ when $p<1$ then the answer is no. I could not come up with a counterexample though. Does anybody have a good pointer on how to construct one?

Comment: $L^p$ has no non-trivial convex open sets when $p<1$. I don't know a reference but I can give a proof.

Comment: Not even with the metric defined by $d(f,g)= \int |f-g|^p?$

Comment: the metric would be given by $$d(f,g)=\Bigg(\int\mid f-g\mid^p\Bigg)^\frac{1}{p}$$
but for $p<1$ it doesn't work. Notice every theorem ensuring the $L^p$ norm is indeed a norm actually require $p\geq1$.

Comment: For $p<1$, we do not have a norm, but $d(f,g) = \int |f-g|^p$ does define a translation invariant distance function.

Comment: @HrafnMagnus, see examples 2.19 and 2.20 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/lpspace.pdf), as well as theorem 3.2 for a general result on $L^p$ spaces with $0<p<1$.